# How do I determine where DLL is referenced?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reference

I have just deployed my VB.net VS2008 winforms solution to the test server.

When I did I got an error:

> Unable to install or run the application. The application requires that assembly
>   Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.Server Version 1.0.0.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first.

I however do not know why this requirement was put in place. As far as I know we did not add any reference to this DLL.

I have done searches and there are no matches for "Synchronization" or "Data.Server" etc...

It is not listed in the references folder either.

Any ideas why it's apparently referenced, but not referenced anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assemblies you're referencing can reference other assemblies themselves (which can reference other assemblies (which can reference other...)). You can use NDepends to chase down your full dependency list.

Comment: I looked through manually and found a reference to Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe, when I removed this and rebuilt, it displayed references to the reference DLL, I then was able to remove these adn rebuild successfully. It then worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).